# Kerberos authentification with PowerBuilder 6.5

Tags: single-sign-on, windows-authentication, kerberos, powerbuilder

I would like to setup SSO using Kerberos (Active Directory). Yhis means acquiring kerberos ticket in a Powerbuilder 6.5 application. No possibility to upgrade PB version (yes, really...).
All the users of my program have ever logged in on the Windows Server (2003 or 2008) : RDP session.

Is it possible to get and check Kerberos Ticket with this PowerBuilder version ? How ?

I think it's possible to get the Windows current username thanks to the Windows API, but it isn't not as secure as a kerberos authentication.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: If the user has authenticated to Windows, is it necessary to re-authenticate the user?